# Convergence in probability to some value

Tags: convergence-divergence, self-learning, exponential-distribution

> Find $a$ such that $X_n \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{ P } a $, where $X_n = n^{-1} \sum^n_{i=1} Y_i $, where the $Y_i \sim Exp(2)$ are independent random variables.

I tried:
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}  
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n - a| \ge \varepsilon)
= & \, 1 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(|X_n - a| \leq \varepsilon \right) \\[8pt]
= & \, 1 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(\left|\frac{\sum Y_i}{n} - a\right| \leq \varepsilon \right) \\[8pt]
= & \, 1 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(-\varepsilon \leq\frac{\sum Y_i}{n} - a \leq \varepsilon \right) \\[8pt]
= & \, 1 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left(n(a-\varepsilon) \leq \sum Y_i \leq n(a + \varepsilon) \right) \\[8pt]
= & \, 1 - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left( \sum Y_i \leq n(a + \varepsilon) \right) %
+ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P\left( \sum Y_i   \leq n(a-\varepsilon)\right) \\[8pt]
\end{split}\end{equation*} 
here we have iid, thus
$$P\left( \sum Y_i \leq n(a+\varepsilon) \right) = P( Y_1 \leq n(a+\varepsilon), Y_2 \leq n(a+\varepsilon),...)= [P(Y \leq n(a+\varepsilon) )]^n $$
similarly,
$$P\left( \sum Y_i \leq n(a-\varepsilon) \right) = P( Y_1 \leq n(a-\varepsilon), Y_2 \leq n(a-\varepsilon),...)= [P(Y \leq n(a-\varepsilon) )]^n $$
returning to first equation,
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}  
 =& \, 1-\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} [P(Y \leq -2n(a+\varepsilon) )]^n + \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} [P(Y \leq -2n(a-\varepsilon) )]^n\\[8pt]
 =& \, 1-\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[e^{-2n(a+\varepsilon)}\right]^n + \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[e^{-2n(a-\varepsilon)}\right]^n\\[8pt]
 =& \, 1+\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2n^2(a+\varepsilon)} - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2n^2(a-\varepsilon)}\\[8pt]
 =& \, 1+\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2n^2(a+\varepsilon)} - \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-2n^2(a-\varepsilon)}\\[8pt]
 =& \, 1+0 -0\\[8pt]
 =& \, 1\\[8pt]
\end{split}\end{equation*}
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: why "$P\left( \sum Y_i \leq n(a+\varepsilon) \right) = P( Y_1 \leq n(a+\varepsilon), Y_2 \leq n(a+\varepsilon),...)$"?

Comment: Isn't this just an application of the weak law of large numbers? $X_n$ is the sample mean of exponential rv with parameter $=2$ hence converges in probability to $1/2$.

Comment: might try to prove that $Y_i$ 's are iid exponential distribution, then $\sum Y_i$ follows gamma distribution.

Comment: Alternatively, if you do not wish to appeal to the theorem and would rather prove this particular case of it directly, then the sure method is to mimic the proof of the general case; use Chebyshev's inequality: if $a=1/2$, then $P(|X_n-a|\geq \epsilon)\leq \sigma^2/(n\epsilon^2)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Probably Chebyshev inequality will suffice here as I could not find value for $a$ with gamma distribution. Thanks, anyways!